# Comparação de valores em lista de Tuplas em python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Minha duvida é como posso interagir nessa lista de modo a fazer comparações entre os valores.

```
def trocar(vals, posX, posY):
    temp = vals[posX]
    vals[posX] = vals[posY]
    vals[posY] = temp
    return None


def ordenar(valores):
    tamanho = len(valores) - 1
    troquei = True
    while troquei:
       troquei = False
       for i in range(tamanho):
          if valores[i] > valores[i + 1]:
            trocar(valores, i, i + 1)
            troquei = True
    tamanho -= 1
return valores


lista= [('Ana', 30, 6.69), ('João', 25, 6.11), ('Pedro', 30, 6.69),    ('Maria', 28, 5.45), ('Thiago', 40, 5.45), ('Raquel', 26, 10.0)]

x=ordenar(lista)
print(x) # [('Ana', 30, 6.69), ('João', 25, 6.11), ('Maria', 28, 5.45), ('Pedro', 30, 6.69), ('Raquel', 26, 10.0), ('Thiago', 40, 5.45)]
```

Minha intenção é imprimir os nomes em ordem de acordo com os valores:

1. A primeira ordem é por média.
2. Se uma das médias for igual passo para idade
3. Se a média e a dade forem iguais passo para ordem alfabética dos nomes

No código acima somente um dos objetivos foi alcançado; pegar os nomes em ordem alfabetica

Comment: Isso amigo é da faculdade, e gosto desse metodo de ensino deles , os programas São feitos com o menor uso possivel de metodos e api prontos, tudo é na mão,  não posso utilizar sorted, sort ou qualquer outro metodo do api do python, tenho que fazer no feijão mesmo e tenho que utilizar as funções de ordenação que postei (def trocar e def ordenar),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu exemplo uma lista de tuplas está sendo ordenada. Na lógica atual você está usando o operador `>` para comparar duas tuplas. Isso faz sentido uma vez que uma tupla é uma sequência, e conforme - tradução livre da - [documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> Sequências são comparadas lexicograficamente através da comparação de elementos correspondentes. [...] Coleções que suportam comparações de ordem são ordenadas conforme seus primeiros elementos desiguais (por exemplo, `[1,2,x] <= [1,2,y]` tem o mesmo valor que `x <= y`).

Sabendo disso, o truque para ordenar uma lista de tuplas corretamente está em rearranjar os elementos de cada tupla conforme seu critério de comparação. No caso, você deseja transformar uma tupla `(nome, idade, media)` em uma tupla `(media, idade, nome`) para fins de comparação.

Assumindo que as médias devem ser ordenadas de maneira descendente e os demais elementos em ordem ascendente a implementação ficaria assim:

```
def rearranjar_tupla(tupla):
    return (-tupla[2], tupla[1], tupla[0])
    
def ordenar(valores):
    tamanho = len(valores) - 1
    troquei = True
    while troquei:
       troquei = False
       for i in range(tamanho):
          if rearranjar_tupla(valores[i]) > rearranjar_tupla(valores[i + 1]):
            trocar(valores, i, i + 1)
            troquei = True
    tamanho -= 1
    return valores
```

***[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ivPOjg)***

Se as médias também devem ser ordenadas de maneira ascendente basta inverter as posições da tupla com [*extended slice*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices):

```
def rearranjar_tupla(tupla):
    return tupla[::-1]
```

***[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/VzzVrX)***

É importante ressaltar porém que, para além de fins de aprendizado, reinventar a roda não costuma ser uma boa ideia. Além do código extra, esse algoritmo de ordenação básico (*Bubble Sort*) é caro do ponto de vista de Complexidade Assintótica (*O(n²)*) e muito ruim do ponto de vista de *cache hits* e administração de memória (múltiplas cópias e *swaps* desnecessários colocam pressão no *Garbage Collector*).

Os [mecanismos de ordenação da API padrão do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) se valem de um algoritmo bastante robusto chamado [Timsort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), capaz de ordenar coleções de maneira eficiente, com Complexidade Assintótica *O(n*log(n))* no pior caso.

Utilizando a biblioteca padrão do Python podemos substituir todo o código do primeiro exemplo por uma única linha de código:

```
lista.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[2], x[1], x[0]))
```

***[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/sxdSBw)***

---

### Fontes

1. [SOen - How does tuple comparison work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5292303/664577)
2. [The Python Language Reference - Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons)
3. [What’s New in Python 2.3 - Extended Slices](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices)
4. [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)
5. [Wikipedia - Timsort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela ajuda, essa dica vai me ajudar muito, agora vou tentar fazer uma implementação para mostrar a classificação  dos alunos de acordo com os critérios, acho que terei que comparar as listas de tuplas geradas , vou gerar 3 listas, uma ordenada por media , outra ordenada por idade e outra ordenada por nome.

Comment: Oi Bruno, salvo engano meu acredito que a classificação seja o primeiro exemplo (maiores médias primeiro, desemparados por menor idade e finalmente ordem alfabética).

Comment: Isso Anthony, primeiro é feito a comparação com a média se as médias forem iguais o desempate é por idade se continuar igual ai vem o desempate por nome e no fim imprimo somente os nomes dos alunos por ordem de classificação.