# Comparar valores em uma lista de tuplas

Tags: python

```
 lista  = [('Maria', 28, 7.0), ('Ana', 30, 9.0), ('Thiago', 30, 9.0)]
 resultado = []
 for i in lista:
    if i[2]<i[2]+1:
        resultado.append(i[0])
 print(resultado)
```

Saída correta: `Ana, Thiago, Maria`

Minha saída está `Maria, Ana , Thiago`. O que nos dá que não foi feita a comparação com os valores média e depois idade e nem nome.
Gostaria de uma ajuda de como posso comparar os valores dessa lista e imprimir em ordem, primeira comparação por média se média for igual passo para idade se idade for igual passo para nome, estou a duas semanas tentando resolver esse problema estou com muita dificuldades.

Comment: Olá Anthony, eu continuei tendo dificuldades em montar meu código, tentei fazer a mesma pergunta utilizando o mesmo link de ontem mas não consegui, vou procurar melhorar, resolvi tentar mais uma pergunta em relação ao código, mas agora vou juntar as respostas e estudar a melhor maneira para termina-lo, assim que conseguir publico o resultado final, agradeço a todos .

Comment: Olá Bruno por favor não duplique perguntas com o mesmo conteúdo. Entre a resposta na pergunta original e as duas respostas nessa pergunta você possui três respostas (bastante semelhantes) sobre como ordenar sua lista e criar o *ranking* corretamente ordenado com todos os campos. Se as soluções propostas não estão claras ou não atendem seu problema por algum motivo vale a pena refinar sua pergunta para que possamos entender em que exatamente você está tendo dificuldade.

Answer (score 4):

Duas semanas é muito tempo, visto que consegues resolver em 1/2 linhas d:

```
lista = [('Thiago', 30, 9.0), ('Maria', 28, 7.0), ('Ana', 30, 9.0)]
ordered = sorted(lista, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[1], x[0]))
print(ordered) # [('Maria', 28, 7.0), ('Ana', 30, 9.0), ('Thiago', 30, 9.0)]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/EgV2g9)

Se quiseres em ordem inversa:

```
...
ordered = sorted(lista, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
# [('Thiago', 30, 9.0), ('Ana', 30, 9.0), ('Maria', 28, 7.0)]
...
```

O truque está no argumento `key` cujo o valor é função em que podes definir por que valor(s) deve ordenar.

[DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela resposta, o problema é que não posso utilizar ' sort' e 'sorted', tenho que fazer na mão, é essa minha dificuldade, já tentei if,for mas não consigo meu objetivo. Estou na luta.

Comment: Tenho que fazer comparações entre média, idade e se esses forem iguais tenho que ordenar os nomes em ordem alfabética.

Comment: @bruno, você não especificou na pergunta que não poderia utilizar a função `sorted`. Nesses casos você precisa deixar isso bem explícito.

Comment: @BrunoSilva o Anderson tem razão, no 'mundo real' seria assim que era feito, para motivos didáticos como o teu devias ter especificado isso, eu não teria dado esta resposta se soubesse que era esse o caso

Comment: Pessoal  peço desculpas por não ter colocado corretamente minha pergunta vou procurar melhorar mais e mais, obrigado pela atenção dos senhores, vou continuar na luta.

Comment: Gostaria de uma ajuda, eu consigo somar as notas e gerar essa lista de tuplas com o nome , idade e media mas não consigo fazer a comparação das medias e se  as medias forem iguais tenho que comparar as idades de forma que maior idade primeiro candidato.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar a resposta do Miguel, mostro uma forma de implementar a ordenação que pretende "na mão". Convém frisar que numa situação real não há necessidade de fazer isso, por vários motivos, e uma implementação sua muito provavelmente será bem menos eficiente que a implementação nativa já fornecida (assim como a que eu demonstro nesta resposta).

Por simplicidade optei pelo [*Selection Sort*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) relembrando que outros algoritmos serão mais eficientes tais como *QuickSort*, *MergeSort*, *HeapSort* entre outros que garantem complexidade de tempo na ordem de O(nlogn).

Exemplo:

```
lista = [('Thiago', 30, 9.0), ('Maria', 28, 7.0), ('Ana', 30, 9.0)]
resultado = [i for i in lista]  # passar tudo da lista para resultado
tamanho = len(resultado)  # achar e guardar o tamanho

for i in range(0, tamanho):  # para cada posição da lista
    menor = i  # pre-definir o menor como o elemento corrente
    for j in range(i + 1, tamanho):  # percorrer os restantes para achar o menor
        # se este é menor    
        if resultado[j][2] < resultado[menor][2] or \
                (resultado[j][2] == resultado[menor][2] and resultado[j][1] < resultado[menor][1]) or \
                (resultado[j][1] == resultado[menor][1] and resultado[j][0] < resultado[menor][0]):
            menor = j  # guarda a posição

    if resultado[i] != resultado[menor]:  # se achou um menor diferente do corrente
        # faz a troca de posição entre o corrente e o menor
        temp = resultado[menor]
        resultado[menor] = resultado[i]
        resultado[i] = temp

print(resultado)
```

O `if` dentro do segundo `for` é o que define a forma como os elementos são ordenados pois é o que define qual o menor elemento para aquela posição. Note que comecei por comparar a posição `[j][2]` ou seja no elemento corrente a posição `2` que corresponde à média:

```
if resultado[j][2] < resultado[menor][2]
```

Caso não seja menor mas seja igual, vai agora comparar com outro valor do mesmo elemento, a idade que está na posição `1`:

```
or \
(resultado[j][2] == resultado[menor][2] and resultado[j][1] < resultado[menor][1])
```

E caso a posição `1` seja igual compara pelo nome que está na posição `0`:

```
or \
(resultado[j][1] == resultado[menor][1] and resultado[j][0] < resultado[menor][0]):
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/8Njphl)

Comment: Oi Isaac. O `if` interno estabelecendo regras de desempate posição a posição é desnecessário. Por padrão, ao comparar tuplas, o operador `<` já desempata valores iguais da esquerda para a direita. Ou seja, para ordenar através de múltiplos critérios basta rearranjar a tupla para conter a média na primeira posição, idade da segunda, e nome na terceira. Veja minha resposta na pergunta original do OP: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289780/100

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Obrigado pelo comentário. Não sabia de facto desse pormenor de comparação nativa de tuplas, mas acaba por tornar o algoritmo mais simples.

Comment: olá Isac.Muito obrigado pela resposta, vou lutar pra tentar   chegar no seu nivel e tambem no nivel do Anthony Accioly,  vocês são mestres mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, peço desculpas pelos erros, sou novo no site e vou procurar melhorar minhas perguntas e respostas.